# Tool indicators dissapearing in blender 2.91

Tags: edit-mode

As the title says, sometimes when working, my indicators disappear, for example: in edit mode when using one of the tools like vertex slide, shear or anything else, normally a little visible box or handles show what you are editing. Often its gone and it only comes back after i restart blender. Just want to know if this is a common bug in the beta or just me accidentally clicking something.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: @LawrenceAS thanks for your reply, here my screeenshot !